# I cannot set while to work properly in for loops in ts

Tags: arrays, typescript, loops, asynchronous, while-loop

I want to get array of arrays with unique values, but at some point

> while

gets missed or ignored (I presume because of the asynchronous nature of it). Can someone help with a adding a promise to this, or setting

> async/await

structure or giving better advise how to check the arrays. I tried adding

> async/await

but I get error and I am not sure where I can add a promise or use it. It is

```
getSeveralArrays() {
 for (let index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
        this.getValue();
      }
}
getValue() {

    this.i++;

    this.array = [];
    this.randomArray = [];
for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {

    this.randomValue = this.getRandom();

    if (this.array.length === 2) {

        while ((this.array[0] === this.randomValue) || (this.array[1] === this.randomValue)) {
            this.randomValue = this.getRandom();
        }

        this.array.push(this.randomValue);


    } else if (this.array.length === 3) {

        while ((this.array[0] === this.randomValue) || (this.array[1] === this.randomValue) || (this.array[2] === this.randomValue)) {
            this.randomValue = this.getRandom();
        }

        this.array.push(this.randomValue);


    } else {

        this.array.push(this.randomValue);

    }

    console.log({...this.array});

    this.randomArray.push({ind: this.i, val: this.array});

    }
}


  getRandom() {

      const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
      return value;
  }
```

Comment: there is no need to use `async` code as you are not using `Promise`. Could you write desired result as text and source data as text. It would be really helpful to understand what you would like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing asynchronous in all your code, so no need for `async/await`. Also, `while` is not asynchronous.

You were missing a case for the length of 1 though, so the second element could always be the same as the first.

```js
class X {
  getSeveralArrays() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
      this.getValue();
    }
  }
  getValue() {
    this.i++;

    this.array = [];
    this.randomArray = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
      this.randomValue = this.getRandom();

      if (this.array.length === 1) {
        while (this.array[0] === this.randomValue) {
          this.randomValue = this.getRandom();
        }

        this.array.push(this.randomValue);
      } else if (this.array.length === 2) {
        while (this.array[0] === this.randomValue || this.array[1] === this.randomValue) {
          this.randomValue = this.getRandom();
        }

        this.array.push(this.randomValue);
      } else if (this.array.length === 3) {
        while (
          this.array[0] === this.randomValue ||
          this.array[1] === this.randomValue ||
          this.array[2] === this.randomValue
        ) {
          this.randomValue = this.getRandom();
        }

        this.array.push(this.randomValue);
      } else {
        this.array.push(this.randomValue);
      }

      console.log({ ...this.array });

      this.randomArray.push({ ind: this.i, val: this.array });
    }
  }

  getRandom() {
    const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    return value;
  }
}

console.log(new X().getSeveralArrays());
```

Also, all those checks can be simplified:

```js
      while (this.array.some(value => value === this.randomValue)) {
        this.randomValue = this.getRandom();
      }
```

And generally, just as a small code review: If you do not need to access something from another class method (or somewhere outside), you should not put all those values into class properties, but keep them as values inside your functions.

So `this.randomValue` and `this.array` should just be defined within your function with `let` or `const`.

Comment: Thank you so mush for your answer! Also your simplification method is much better and more readable. Have a nice day!